# 'I wish my mum wouldn’t phone me every five minutes!' Do I say that sentence to someone while I am talking with my mum on the phone?

Tags: wish

**Update 29/09/2023**

I found the following sentence on [7ESL](https://7esl.com/use-wish-in-english-i-wish-if-only/):

> I **wish** my mum **would** not phone me every five minutes!

Is my mum still on the phone now? Do I say that sentence to someone while I am talking with my mum on the phone?

Comment: The statement is silent in that regard. Mum could be on the phone now, or not. If she is on the phone, presumably you'd be speaking to a friend, with your hand cupped over the phone's microphone.

Comment: Seems likely that this is something you would say after just getting off the phone with her, or seeing her name appear on caller display as she is calling you.

Comment: Yes, it would be very rude to say it in the middle of a call when your mum would hear. But it's not clear what part of the sentence you are puzzled by. Do you want to know why "wish" is in that particular tense, or why it's "wouldn't" rather than something else (what?)? Is there some other situation you are interested in?

Comment: @TimR  _with your hand cupped over the phone's microphone_ can you do that with what even I think of as a 'phone' these days?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Mum works for Apple and keeps calling to push a phone upgrade. *Get rid of that old flip-phone, Marios!*

Comment: @TimR - if my mother worked for Apple, I'd disown her!

Comment: I assume this is related to your previous question about “wish”: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/340341/are-the-sentences-i-wish-my-car-would-start-and-i-wish-the-lesson-would-end I would say that there is an implication that the situation of “phoning every five minutes” is ongoing, but it’s unknown whether an active phone call is happening. “every five minutes” could be hyperbole too, and it might just mean “more often than I’d like”.

Comment: @StuartF Hi! Sorry for answering too late. I wonder if my mum is on the phone when I say that sentence. All users here helped me to answer my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 29/09/2023**

I found in Cambridge Dictionary the following [1](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/wish):

> **Wish+would**
>
> We can use **wish+would** if we are annoyed about something that is or is not happening, or about something that will or will not happen.
>
> **Examples:**
>
> - I **wish** you **would** stop making so much noise! (You are making a noise; it would be better if you didn’t.)
> - I **wish** you **would** not come through the kitchen with your dirty boots on. (You do come through the kitchen; it would be better if you didn’t.)

Cambridge Dictionary doesn't give examples about something that will or will not happen.

I found in BritishCouncil the following [2](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/grammar/english-grammar-reference/wishes-hypotheses):

> We use past tense modals **would** and **could** to talk about wishes for the future:
>
> **Examples:**
>
> - I don't like my work. I **wish** I **could** get a better job.
> - That's a dreadful noise. I **wish** it **would** stop.

When we use the structure **"wish+would"**,the thing wished for is not happening now. When we use the structure **"wish+would+not"** the thing wished for is happening now!

The sentence in the question is the following :

> I **wish** my mum **would** not phone me every five minutes!

That sentence refers to the present. We are annoyed about something that is happening now. My mum can be on the phone now, or not.

I can say that sentence when I see her name on the mobile display as she is calling me or when I hang up on her. If I am very rude, I can say that sentence to someone in the middle of a call when my mum can hear me. If I don't want my mum to hear me, I can say that sentence to someone in the middle of a call with my hand cupped over the phone's microphone.

Comment: Someone downvoted my question and my answer. I edited my answer again. Now my answer is perfect! Could you please consider revising your downvotes?

Comment: Hello, Marios. I rarely contribute on ELL, partly because I feel unfamiliar with the ethos, particularly the tenor of voting. The first two comments under your question address how the modal is used in such cases, while the third addresses the need for politeness. Your answer seems accurate, but does not mention the others (Tim; Daniel ...) who have already responded correctly (though ELU would expect references, as you give; I'm not clear about ELL policy on this).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you very much! Do you like my question? It's correct and 2 persons downvoted it.

Comment: I won't comment on ELL policy (and certainly not on voting habits here), but I'd not be put off by setbacks. I could understand the downvotes if the question had been asked on ELU, which is intended more for questions experienced linguists might have.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Hi! Thank you very much for everything!