# Using "beneath which" or just use "above"?

Tags: prepositional-phrases

Choice A

> A bright sky far `beneath which` the square of this building.

Choice B

> A bright sky far `beneath which` the square of this building `is`.

Choice C

> A bright sky far `above` the square of this building.

Are all three correct?

Which one is better for describing the relation of a sky and a buiding in a place where we are?

Comment: Hi. What do you mean by "the square of this building"?  A and C are incomplete sentences because they have no verb.  Where did you find these?

Comment: @BillyKerr
A square next or in front of the building.
I try to describe a scene I saw when I was standing at that buiding.

Comment: @BillyKerr Because the square and that building belong the same construction.

Comment: Then you should probably say "the square next to/in front of this building" to avoid confusion.  The "square of this building" is a bit odd.  There are other words for such squares: "courtyard "or perhaps "quadrangle" that are part of a building.

Comment: None of them are valid sentences. #1 is just a noun and an incomplete relative clause, #2 should have the verb *(**is**)* before the subject *(**the square...**)*, and #3 is just a noun phrase without a verb.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Is it Okay to express a noun phrase without a verb?

Comment: @BillyKerr The building in ON a university campus. Quadrangle is a good word. –

Comment: Yes, quadrangle is often used for such a square on a university campus.

Comment: Also you spelt "beneath" wrong in two of your examples.

Comment: I could answer your *Is it Okay to express a noun phrase without a verb?* with just the word ***Yes.*** That would be a perfectly valid ***reply*** in the current context, but it's not a ***sentence*** by most definitions, because it has no verb.

Answer (score 1):

*Above the square* is a prepositional phrase which can be attached to a noun phrase (or other things).

*Beneath which the square is* is a relative clause which requires a noun phrase to attach to.

*Beneath which the square* is an incomplete structure, apparently a relative clause but lacking a verb.

Comment: Hi! I upvoted your good answer! I have a problem. I asked a question. I answered it because nobody answered it. On this site they hate me and they downvoted my question and my answer. Both of them are correct! I will be happy if you read them and upvote or downvote them. I am going to delete my comment later. Thank you very much! [1]:https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/340464/i-wish-my-mum-wouldn-t-phone-me-every-five-minutes-do-i-say-that-sentence-to